# What is the default setting for JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

What is the default setting for JScrollPane? Which one is it?

```
VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED
VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS
VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER
```

Comment: It's `VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED`: *"Creates an empty (no viewport view) `JScrollPane` where both horizontal and vertical scrollbars appear when needed."* ([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#JScrollPane%28%29)).

Comment: Just look in the docs - that's what they're there for. Easy, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of JScrollPane says:

> Creates an empty (no viewport view) `JScrollPane`
>    where both horizontal and vertical scrollbars appear when needed.

And the code is:

```
public JScrollPane() {
    this(null, VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
}
```

So, it's as needed for both.

Answer (score 2):

The default policy is `VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED`. This applies to the vertical and horizontal scrollbars.